# How to filter Age from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I was trying to create a filter on the `datagridview` using `combobox`. 
What I wanted to do is to filter the filtered data in the `datagridview`.
I have seven `comboboxes` for the filtration. For example, the first `combobox` is for the Year then I still want to filter the search into Grade level, then to Section and so on. So, the user will be able to sort or filter his search from the database.

So far I have my stored procedure code and tried it in the combo box. The `SchoolYear`, `Grade`, `section`, `Gender`, `status`, `Account` filtering works well.. Aside from age, I set my query to compute the age automatically without saving into database, now my problem is to filter the age.

I did my stored procedure this way.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspYearGradeFilter]
    @Year Nvarchar(20) = NULL,
    @Grade Nvarchar(20) = NULL,
    @Section Nvarchar(20) = NUll,
    @Gender Nvarchar(20) = NULL,
    @Status Nvarchar(20) = NULL,
    @Status2 Nvarchar(20) = NULL,
    @Age Nvarchar(20) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        si.StudentID, SI.Surname, SI.FirstName, SI.MiddleName, 
        si.Gender, si.BirthDay, SI.TelNum,
        Birthday, getdate() AS [Today],
        Datediff(yy, BirthDay, getdate()) -
            CASE
                WHEN DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY, BirthDay, getdate()), BirthDay) > GETDATE() 
                  THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
            END AS [age]
    FROM 
        StudentInformation SI
    JOIN 
        StudentHistory SH ON SI.StudentID = SH.StudentID
    WHERE 
        sh.SchoolYear LIKE COALESCE('%'+ @Year+'%', sh.SchoolYear)
        AND sh.Levels LIKE COALESCE('%' + @Grade + '%', sh.Levels)
        AND SI.Gender LIKE COALESCE('%' + @Gender + '%', si.gender)
        AND SH.Section LIKE COALESCE('%' + @Section + '%', sh.Section) 
        AND Si.Status LIKE COALESCE('%' + @Status + '%', si.status) 
        AND Sh.Status2 LIKE COALESCE(@Status2 + '%', sh.status2)
        AND [Age] LIKE COALESCE('%' + @Age + '%', [Age])
END
```

But I get an error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure uspYearGradeFilter, Line 42
>   Invalid column name 'Age'

Can someone please help me to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Side note: **why on earth** are you using `nvarchar(20)` for a parameter like `@Year` which **clearly** is a numerical value? Please always use the *most appropriate* datatype - use numerical types for numerical values, date and time types for date&time - not just strings for everything!

Comment: @marc_s - don't you know modern style is every variable be declared as string and then have a `.ToString()` whenever it is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the column alias in the immediate `WHERE` clause. You can use it in the subquery though:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 
        si.StudentID,
        SI.Surname,
        SI.FirstName,
        SI.MiddleName,
        si.Gender,
        si.BirthDay,
        SI.TelNum
        getdate() AS [Today],
        Datediff(yy,BirthDay,getdate()) -
                    CASE
                        WHEN DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY,BirthDay,getdate()),BirthDay) > GETDATE() 
                            THEN 1
                        ELSE 
                            0
                    END AS [age]
    FROM StudentInformation SI
    JOIN StudentHistory SH
        ON SI.StudentID = SH.StudentID
    WHERE 
        sh.SchoolYear LIKE COALESCE('%'+ @Year+'%', sh.SchoolYear)
        AND sh.Levels LIKE COALESCE('%' + @Grade + '%', sh.Levels)
        AND SI.Gender LIKE COALESCE('%' + @Gender + '%', si.gender)
        AND SH.Section LIKE COALESCE('%' + @Section + '%', sh.Section) 
        AND Si.Status LIKE COALESCE('%' + @Status + '%', si.status) 
        AND Sh.Status2 LIKE COALESCE(@Status2 + '%', sh.status2)
) t
WHERE [Age] LIKE COALESCE('%' + @Age + '%', [Age])
```

Comment: Hi Felix, I got an error when i tried your code. It says `The column 'Birthday' was specified multiple times for 't'.
`

Comment: Remove the second Birthday in the subqery.